# How to convert SQS SentTimestamp to C# datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

How to convert the timestamp from AWS SQS queue to C# datetime value?. [SentTimestamp, 1513139344524] this is a sample value in the attributes of one of the message. The region I am using for the queue is ap-southeast-2.

Comment: I tried with that and it throws error. ArgumentOutofRangeException (Value to add was out of range)

Comment: The solution presented in the duplicate is for seconds. AWS SQS timestamps are in milliseconds, so you'll need to change that function that adds Seconds to AddMilliseconds and try again. This was detailed in one of the comments on that answer.

Comment: Could you share the code you have already try'd

Comment: Thanks for your help @Yannick. It worked with milliseconds.